# How to activate a macro by clicking in a cell with a formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to activate a macro by clicking in a cell.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B37")) Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("DaysEditor").Activate
        Sheets("DaysEditor").Columns("C:LY").Hidden = False
        Sheets("DaysEditor").Columns("C:EX").Hidden = True
        Sheets("DaysEditor").Range("A1").Select
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

This code works on a cell that doesn't have a formula but will not work on cells with a formula in them.

Comment: Are you clicking on `B37`? Not sure why you need to intersect that since you are using a single cell for the target range but anyways - make sure you are clicking on the correct cell. The contents of the cell is meaningless for what you are using.

Comment: @K.Davis I found this code here on stackoverflow and adopted it to my sheet.  Like i said, if i have that in a cell that I manually typed in and click on it, then it works perfectly. But if I have that linked to a cell with a formula (Which is also a merged cell) it will not work.

Comment: See there's critical information you didn't tell us about. "Merged Cells" are more than 1 cell, right? So your code bypasses the `If Selection.Count = 1` portion. Again, nothing to do with the contents of the cell.

Comment: @K.Davis Ah. Ok. Yes the cell I am trying to attach this too is actually B35 and B36 merged to one cell.  So if I change the Selection.Count = 2 it should work? Or will i have to do something else?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs I just tried that and IT WORKS.  THANK YOU very much for your help!!!

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve your problem

Comment: Note: merged cells are a **nightmare**. Avoid them! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few minor tweaks I would change with your code. Firstly, if you are going to make multiple calls to a worksheet, I suggest that you either make a variable of it or use it within a `With <obj>` statement.

`Worksheets()` is essentially a function. Every time you use it it has to get the function's "value" - hence not the most efficient way of doing things.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$B$37:$C$37" Then
        With Worksheets("DaysEditor")
            .Columns("C:LY").Hidden = False
            .Columns("C:EX").Hidden = True
            .Activate
            .Range("A1").Select
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Generally I advise against using the `Activate` method. But since you appear to actually want to be on the worksheet when the code runs then it's not a big deal here. Just remember that `Activate` is not necessary for the remainder of your code to function.

One last tweak is that I moved your `Activate` method *after* you hide/unhide the columns. Probably not a big deal either, but no need to watch the screen redraw unnecessarily.

Comment: Thank you for this! This works perfectly. I actually want to activate the screen. What is happening it I have this macro running for every month in a calendar, and if you click on the month name, then it takes you to another sheet and it hides all the columns before the start of that month.  I am also working on another issue with conditionally formatting on the same sheet, and attached photos if you wanted a better idea of what im doing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59342294/is-it-possible-to-conditionally-format-cells-and-link-them-to-a-filtered-table-o

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @K.Davis he helped me figure out that the problem was the that cell I was attaching this to was a merged cell and that was the problem. I changed the Selection.Count = 1 to Selection.Count = 2 and the code works perfectly!

Comment: You would probably be better off using `If target.address = "$B$37:$C$37" Then ...`. But that's just me thinking out loud. You can replace both of your If statements with that line.

Comment: @K.Davis If i were to use that, would i take away Selection.Count and the If Not statement and just have an "If Target.Address = my cell then.... rest of my code?  I am about to post another problem I am having with this sheet about trying to link cells and conditionally format them. Thanks

Comment: Yes that is correct. You would remove both. And this would allow targets to be 1 or 2 cells, and you could place your address criteria into a select case statement if necessary. `Select Case Target.Address : Case "$B$37:$C$37"`. Also remember that `Selection` is actually your `Target`, so I wouldn't use selection anyway.

Comment: @K.Davis Awesome. I just tried this and it works perfectly. I will adobt this into my code for this. ( I have that same code running on 12 different spots, so taking out 2 lines worth on each one will make a good difference.) Thanks.